# Spring data jpa repositories scope

Tags: spring, scope, spring-data-jpa, spring-bean

What is default scope generated repositories in spring data jpa module ? Can we change that scope using spring `@Scope` anntotation ?

```
@Scope("session")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

Comment: Singleton. Why would you want to change the scope? You aren't keeping state in there so making them something else as a singleton is pretty much useless.

Comment: Good point! :) but, i'm interested, is this possible ? :)

Comment: I don't think the `@Scope` annotation is taken into account, so you would have to hack/tap into the repository generation yourself.